# Output won't print as required

Tags: python

I'm getting this output :

```
self.__statsOpen = self.__default += 1
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

when I use this code:

```
class ticketStats(object):

    ticket_sum = ticket.counter - 2000

    def __init__(self):
        self.__default = 0

    def __statsAll(self):
        return ticket_sum

    def __statsOpen(self):
        for i in range(self.statsAll):
            if supportResponse.resolve()  == "Ticket Status: Open":  
                self.__statsOpen = self.__default += 1
            elif supportResponse.resolve()  == "Ticket Status: Closed":
                self.__statsOpen = self.__default -= 1

    def __statsClosed(self):
        for i in range(self.statsAll):
            if supportResponse.resolve()  == "Ticket Status: Closed":
                self.__statsClosed = self.__default += 1 
            elif supportResponse.resolve() == "Ticket Status: Open":
                self.__statsClosed = self.__default -= 1       
    
    def displayStats(self):
        print("\nDisplaying Ticket Statistics\n")
        print("Tickets Created: " + str(self.__statsAll) + "Tickets Resolved: " + str(self.__statsClosed) + "Tickets To Solve: " + str(self.__statsOpen))
```

And this output when I remove self.__default += 1 / -= 1 parts

```
Displaying Ticket Statistics

Tickets Created: <bound method ticketStats.__statsAll of <__main__.ticketStats object at 0x00D88470>>Tickets Resolved: <bound method ticketStats.__statsClosed of <__main__.ticketStats object at 0x00D88470>>Tickets To Solve: <bound method ticketStats.__statsOpen of <__main__.ticketStats object at 0x00D88470>>
```

These are my instances so I'm trying to get an output of tickets created : 3 tickets resolved: 1 tickets to solve: 2

```
t1 = ticketCreation("Inna", "INNAM", "inna@whitecliffe.co.nz", "My monitor stopped working")
t1R = supportResponse("sucks")
t2 = ticketCreation("", "MARIAH", "", "Request for video camera to conduct webinars")
t2R = supportResponse("")
t3 = ticketCreation("Joel", "JOELS", "", "change password")
t3R = supportResponse("")
t4 = ticketStats()

print("\nPrinting Tickets:\n")

t1.autoAssign()
t1.displayTicket()
t1R.respond()
t1R.resolve()
print()

t2.autoAssign()
t2.displayTicket()
t2R.respond()
t2R.resolve()
print()

t3.autoAssign()
t3.displayTicket()
t3R.respond()
t3R.resolve()

t4.displayStats()
```

Comment: Yes, that is a syntax error.  If that's really what you want, you'll need to use two statements:  `self.__default += 1` and `self.__statsOpen = self.__default`.

Comment: And if you want to run the `__statsAll` function, then you need to use parens: `self.__statsAll()`.  Same with `__statsClosed` and `__statsOpen`.

Comment: Actually, now that I look at it, the code is nonsense.  You have a `__statsOpen` function, but the function REPLACES `__statsOpen` by assigning an integer to it, thereby deleting the function.  What do you want these functions to return?

Comment: `self.statsAll` does not exist.  What is that supposed to contain?  And your loops over `self.statsAll` don't ever use the loop variable.  I cannot even guess what you expect this code to do.  Perhaps you should describe the problem in words.

Comment: Sorry, I'm incredibly new at this. Basically I need to have a default value of 0 for each variable I need to print. The method __statsAll() should count the overall amount of tickets submitted (so that would be 3 in this case, using the ticket counter I have in a separate class), __statsOpen() (the method, ill rename all them) to increment by 1 for each ticket thats open, decrement by 1 for each ticket closed, and the same situation for __statsClosed() to increment and decrement by 1. Wanted it to overall display how many tickets were created, how many are closed, and how many are still open.

Comment: Here's the problem: how can we possibly KNOW whether and when a ticket is created, opened, or closed?  We don't have any insight into `ticketCreation` or `supportResponse`.  Presumably, THOSE are the objects that know the statistics.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using `self.__statsOpen = self.__default + 1`
as opposed to `self.__statsOpen = self.__default += 1`?

The issue might be that the `+=` in addition to the `=` means you're defining `self.__statsOpen` as well as defining `self.__default`, and maybe Python can't handle that?